# Crypto librarys in Mono not found

Tags: c#, mono, cryptoapi

I have a problem compiling a C# program with mono in Ubuntu 14.04, mono version: 3.2.8. It tells me that the Crypto Library ECDiffieHellmanCng and the ECDsaCng references are missing. 
I found out that they are not implemented in mono yet. I tried this reference design from Microsoft:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Security/Cryptography/ECDsaCng.cs,27778745e2b25dfa
But a lot of libraries are missing afterwards, and it gets a never ending story. (I added a lot bet then it says that some stuff is already implemented in the namespace)
Do you have any ideas what I could try else?
Should I just compile it with MS and then try it with Wine?

Comment: Have you considered Bouncy Castle?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer
No i didnt found that one
would you add the source files to the project and use them ?
Or would you just use the dll

Comment: Which source files and which dlls are you talking about?

Comment: http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/ these ones

Comment: Don't bother adding the dlls or compiling the libs. There is a nuget package.